# How add button in DataGridView

Tags: c#

How can I add button to my DataGridView code, in two cell (c#)

table have 4 columns, and dinamically rows;
last two columns had button.

Code is:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

DataColumn col1 = new DataColumn("Típus (Név)", typeof(string));
DataColumn col2 = new DataColumn("Ertéke", typeof(string));
DataColumn col3 = new DataColumn("Szerkesztés",typeof(Button));
DataColumn col4 = new DataColumn("Törlés",typeof(Button));   

table.Columns.Add(col1);
table.Columns.Add(col2);
table.Columns.Add(col3);
table.Columns.Add(col4);

foreach (var item in data)
{
  string[] listdata = item.Split('|');
  DataRow row = table.NewRow();
  string nev = listdata[0];
  string ertek = listdata[1];
  DataGridViewButtonCell torol = new DataGridViewButtonCell();
  torol.Tag = listdata[2];
  Button szerkeszt = new Button();
  szerkeszt.Text = "Edit";
  Button Torol = new Button();
  Torol.Text = "Delete";
  row[col1] = nev;                  
  row[col2] = ertek;
  row[col3] = szerkeszt;
  row[col4] = Torol;
  table.Rows.Add(row);
}

DataGridView gvTest = new DataGridView();
gvTest.DataSource = table;
gvTest.Size = new Size(700,400);
gvTest.Font = new Font(gvTest.Font.Name,13);
gvTest.ReadOnly = true;

panel.Controls.Add(gvTest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn btn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
gvTest.Columns.Add(btn);
btn.HeaderText = "Click Data";
btn.Text = "Click Here";
btn.Name = "btn";
```

[More Reference here](http://csharp.net-informations.com/datagridview/csharp-datagridview-button.htm)